# using rateYo and willvincent/laravel-rateable

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to fetch the attribute of a rating, however im getting

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: rating in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/elirating/app/Book.php on line 33

Im using [laravel ratable](https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable)

Ideally i would like to fetch the user ratings.

so i can call it out on blade like this

`{{ $book->getRatingAttribute}}`

so it can output for example

`4.5`

**Book.php**

```
<?php
use willvincent\Rateable\Rateable;
use App\User;
use App\Rate;

public function getRatingAttribute()
{
    return Rate::where('rating', $this->attributes['rating']);
}
```

**Rate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;


use App\User;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use willvincent\Rateable\Rateable;

class Rate extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'rating'
    ];


    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'ratings';


}
```

**Schema**

```
class CreateRatingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ratings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('rating');
            $table->morphs('rateable');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index();
            $table->index('rateable_id');
            $table->index('rateable_type');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('ratings');
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be called like this `{{ $book->rating}}` in blade

Comment: it didn't work, i need to refer to `averageRating` in the book model, thats apart of the rateable function. 

when i do this 

      `{{ $book->averageRating}}` in blade it works, but i need to  have this on the book model

Comment: do you have any relation between `Book` and `Rating` ?

Comment: no i don't, i just pass it in blade and it works.  `{{ $book->averageRating}}` but it doesnt fetch the `getRatingAttribute`

Comment: you have `rateable_id` and `rateable_type` in ratings table right ? How does book get ratings ?

Comment: `data-rateyo-rating="{{ $book->rating}}"` i need to fetch the average of ratings. when a user goes to a book page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176843/discussion-between-rkj-and-barnowl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable package for rateable. If you look it has `rateable` trait and it has all the function that you can use, You can check it [here](https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable/blob/master/src/Rateable/Rateable.php)

So display rating in template you can use `{{ $book->averageRating}}` and for submitting ratings you can use `hidden` field. So, it should be like this in form

```
<div id="rateYo" data-rateyo-rating="{{ $book->averageRating or 0}}"> ></div>
<input name="rating" value='{{ $book->averageRating or 0}}' type="hidden" id="val">
```

Here the `rateYo` javascript library change the `rating` value and it saved in hidden filed.